# VBA Outlook Email, update current/selected field before sending

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote a macro, where the starting time of a meeting should be entered into the "Subject" Field of a meeting and the mail will be automatically send right after.

When I start the macro through a button and the last selected field like Subject or Start Time is selected and changed, the email will be send, but with the old data.

[image: Example below]

For example:
My last input to the email was the text "Test" in the empty Subject field. After that I send the email, through the button.
The email is sent, but the subject field remains empty.

Is there a way to update fields like subject and starttime?

I tried to use commands like update, SendKeys "{TAB}", myItem.Close olDiscard to close and update the field and send it right after.

```vb
Sub startTimeSend()
    On Error GoTo HandleErr

        Dim myItem As Object
        Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Dim oldTitle As String
        Dim startTime As String
        Dim scanForOldNr As String
        Dim newStartTimeFormat As String
        
'       olPromptForSave
'        SendKeys "{ENTER}"
'        SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
'        Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")

        oldTitle = myItem.Subject
        startTime = myItem.Start

'        MsgBox (oldTitle)
        

'       scanForOldNr contains third char (usually ":")
        scanForOldNr = Mid(oldTitle, 3, 1)
        If scanForOldNr Like "*:*" Then
'       7 da es von 1 hochzählt nicht null
'            MsgBox (scanForOldNr)
            oldTitle = Mid(oldTitle, 7)
        End If

'        Cancel = True
        
        newStartTimeFormat = Format(startTime, "hh:mm")
        myItem.Subject = newStartTimeFormat & " " & oldTitle

        myItem.Send

ExitHere:
            Exit Sub


HandleErr:
'        Cancel = False

        Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Save` before sending.

Comment: Without showing us the macro you try using, I am afraid that you cannot receive any help. Anyhow, showing the problematic code is required when place a question...

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: code is now updated

Comment: With `myItem.Close olDiscard` removed from just before `oldTitle = myItem.Subject` it appears all is well.

Comment: @niton I removed `myItem.Close olDiscard`, but in the subject field the text "Test" is removed and only the starttime is left in the subject field.

Comment: Does not appear possible but uncomment `MsgBox (scanForOldNr)` to see if the first 6 characters of `oldTitle` are being removed.

Comment: @niton tried `MsgBox (scanForOldNr)` also before the `if`, but `scanForOldNr` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't propagate changes made via OOM to the UI until you close and re-open the item. Or your changes made manually may not be visible in the OOM until the item is saved. I'd suggest dealing with proper OOM properties instead of inventing new mechanisms for sending and receiving data.

Use the [AppointmentItem.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.start) property which returns or sets a `Date` indicating the starting date and time for the Outlook item. To get the associated appointment you can use the [MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem.getassociatedappointment) method.